# Microsoft.Http.dll and associated references

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm working on some WCF Rest services, following some tutorials to make some simple services and then writing console applications to consume them. I am having trouble finding some of the required .dll's to reference in my project.

Does anyone know where I can find the following namespaces?

```
Microsoft.Http
Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web
Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.SpecializedServices
```

I think they may have been in the WCF starter kit originally, but I can't even find that anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd547388

That assembly is part of REST in WCF. It is now named as Web API,

http://www.asp.net/web-api

http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Web%20API%20is%20now%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API

Note that it seems several namespace names have been changed. It is normal for beta bits from Microsoft, but it may break your code.

Comment: @pfeds, it should have been obsolete and removed.

Comment: @Lex-Li Yep, the present equivalent is FormUrlEncodedContent.

Answer (score 0):

These are all part of .NET 4. Make sure that your project is targeting .NET 4 and not .NET 4 Client Profile, which does not include these references.

Comment: I am already, I had to do this to fix a previous problem I was having.